# MS Graph query for member of Group A not already in Group B

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In AzureAD (EntraID) I'm looking to populate a security group ("TargetGroup") with the members of another group ("ReferenceGroup").
Is there a single graph query that will output the users that are in ReferenceGroup but not in TargetGroup?
The issue with using two queries is when the member count is 100k users, both queries take several minutes to complete (what with paging etc), and the final actionable result after comparing them is maybe 2 users.

Previously to solve this, I have used two ms-graph queries, one for TargetGroup and one for ReferenceGroup, then compared the two userlists locally. This works fine when the groups are small but not for large groups.
I've also tried
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<ReferenceGroupId>/members/microsoft.graph.user?$filter=not(memberOf/any(g:g/id eq '<TargetGroupId>'))&$count=true` which doesn't work because memberOf isn't a supported property of User:
`Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'memberOf' of resource 'User'."`

Comment: 'memberOf' is not a property of resource 'User' type but a relationship, so it will probably not work in the filter query